# Can one create an OS using JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, operating-system

This is a question of interest, There are a number of interpreted languages that can be used to create an OS, Can one create an Operating system using PHP or JS.

It does not have to be a fully-fledged OS, at least the one that prints `Hello World`.

Regards

Comment: You seem to have some basic misunderstandings about how interpreters work. An interpreted languages does not "interpret to C++" (or whatever language was used to create the interpreter). Instead an interpreter is a separate program which loads another program into memory, and attempt to read the memory to execute the possible instructions in it. And yes it's possible to create an operating system using interpreted languages. Think about Android which uses the Dalvik *Virtual Machine*.

Comment: With this said, it's actually a little more complicated than that, because many modern interpreted languages are actually compiled to *native* code and not interpreted at all. This is done by the Dalvilk VM (mentioned before) as well as for most Javascript "interpreters". Also, there are actual interpreters for C and C++, which doesn't compile down to native machine code.

Comment: Lastly about the term "operating system " itself... That is a *very* broad term, and can apply to many different levels. Some people considers the direct-to-hardware kernel to be *the* operating system. Others consider only the user-facing parts the operating system. And yet others think of operating systems as a mix of the two. You also have to remember that not all languages expose or have interfaces for direct to hardware communication, which is needed for the lower levels of an OS.

Comment: The major obstacle with developing an OS (the way I understand an OSs role anyway) is that you need some code to interact with peripherals which (at the end of the day) needs to be machine code because that's the only thing the system understands when booting. Interpreters and higher level things will need to be read from somewhere and that somewhere needs code that does the reading. As far as I know PHP or JS do not easily compile down to machine code so unless you write (at least) a PHP or JS to ASM compiler then you're really out of luck

Answer (score 1):

All three of those languages are Turing-complete, so they can simulate any other Turing-complete language. An operating system written in one (or a few) Turing-complete language can also be written in another, assuming that sufficient access to the underlying hardware is provided.

Whether such a thing could be made to be run any any reasonable speed is another matter entirely.

The number of things you can do in programming is virtually limitless, but many of those things require a lot of effort.

Comment: Except that an operating system needs to control the hardware, and PHP doesn't have any way to do that. It calls operating system functions to do that for it.

Comment: But it could run an operating system for emulated hardware, I suppose, not a "real" operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of an operating system is to provide an interface between application programs and the computer hardware, often abstracting away details. In order to do this, the OS code must be able to access the hardware directly (or almost directly, e.g. by calling BIOS functions).

High-level languages like PHP and JavaScript don't have any mechanisms to do this. They depend on an operating system to provide access to hardware at a high level: files, network sockets, etc.

These languages do allow you to link in extension libraries, which give them extra capabilities. But then you're not actually writing the OS in these languages, you're writing it in the language that the extension is written in.

I don't think even C can be used to write an OS if you just stick to the portable features of the language. Operating systems written in C depend on implementation-dependent features such as casting integers to pointers, they use extensions like `asm()`, or they occasionally link with subroutines written in assembly, on order to get direct control of the hardware.